# SAPUI5 - Gateway Errors on update method

Tags: sapui5

I can't seem to get update methods working in SAPUI5.

Here's the example:

```
oModel.update("/JobOfflineSet('" + self.jobId + "')", oEntry, {
        success: function () {
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(self);
        oRouter.navTo("main", {});
        dialog.close();
        },
        error: function (oError) {}
        });
```

And I'm receiving the following error.

There's no error shown in the SAP Gateway and we aren't even getting into ABAP to debug.

```
{"error":{"code":"/IWBEP/CM_MGW_RT/022","message":{"lang":"en","value":"The system cannot return your search. Please try again."},"innererror":{"application":{"component_id":"","service_namespace":"/SAP/","service_id":"ZSV_SURVEY_SRV","service_version":"0001"},"transactionid":"306596E88F59F1CD80C7005056BEAC32","timestamp":"","Error_Resolution":{"SAP_Transaction":"","SAP_Note":"See SAP Note 1797736 for error analysis (https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1797736)","Batch_SAP_Note":"See SAP Note 1869434 for details about working with $batch (https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1869434)"},"errordetails":[{"code":"/IWBEP/CX_MGW_BUSI_EXCEPTION","message":"The system cannot return your search. Please try again.","propertyref":"","severity":"error","target":""}]}}}
```

Comment: Did you check the network tab in the browser and see the request was sent? Also, try setting your break point in the GET_ENTITY method. The gateway framework (by default) first does a GET ENTITY to pull the current data for the entity you're trying to update, then patches the current entity with the updated properties sent in the request. It's possible something in GET_ENTITY errors out, and you would never hit your breakpoint in the update method

Answer (score 3):

This is mostly because UI5 is triggering a `MERGE` method instead of a `PUT` method (To handle MERGE, Gateway internally makes a GET request, which might be failing). You can specify the update method as 'PUT' in the `manifest.json`.

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: "": {
 "dataSource": "mainService",
 "preload": true,
 "settings": {
   "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay",
   "defaultUpdateMethod": "PUT"
 }
},